# Can't completely remove/uninstall wamp64 files

Tags: php, wamp, file-permissions, wampserver, delete-file

I have recently been testing php files for a class. I've been using WampServer to test my code. The last time I used WampServer (about a year ago) I was able to have it fully functional with the green emblem appearing when running. After an update, the MySql Process had been the only process out of the 3 to stop working causing the Yellow/Orange emblem to appear.

I was able to run and test my code but ran into issues when starting to implement database features into the program. After searching online and trying different things, I decided it was best to just reinstall the program. With a clean install, things might get all things working again.

After going to the windows control panel and uninstalling WampServer, I received a message stating not all files could be removed and that I could later manually remove them.

In my computers root folder system C:\wamp64 the folder wamp64 is still there with most of the inside files being removed. All that is left is a bin file with two folders mariadb and mysql. Inside the mysql folder are 2 exe files mysql.exe and mysqlid.exe. When ever I try to delete any of these from the file explorer i get a pop up saying "The action cant be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program."

I have wampserver uninstalled at this point. So I dont know what can be using these processes. Im assuming it might be another program relating to MySql (but thats just a hunch an can be completely wrong).

I've opened taskmanager and cant find anything related to the files.

Ive tried to reinstall wampserver but these files are not replaced when wamperser is reinstalled and I am having the same mysql issues as before.

Ive once again uninstalled wampserver and have the same  C:\wamp64\bin folder not deleted.

If anyone as any had any similar issues and solved this please let me know what you did to resolve the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Type `regedit` in `cmd` and open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` option in it and find `wamp` by pressing `ctrl+F` and if `wamp` found press delete. Finally restart the system and open `C drive` and press `ctrl+delete` on wamp folder. Hope this might helps you!

Alternatively you can use `HelpUninstaller` tool for complete removal. Here is the link to go [helpuninstaller](http://www.helpuninstaller.com/download.php)

Answer (score 1):

[for vmware/bitnami WAMPstack]

WAMP (unlike XAMPP) automatically installs both Apache and MySQL as Services and sets them to auto start.  These stay running after the uninstall completes and will prevent deletion of related WAMP directories/folders.

After reboot (as stated above) they were not running but for system cleanliness you can get rid of the entries with

- sc delete "wampstackApache"
- sc delete "wampstackMySQL"

in an admin or higher cmd.exe.

Be careful of the regedit described above as there are a large  number of "... Windows__CInternal__CSecurity__CAuthentication__CWeb__CWamProvider..." entries which (as far as I can tell) have nothng to do with WAMPstack.

I found the relevant left-over registry entries at:
Computer\HKEY_USERS-\S-1-5-21-3741421246-4127924495-2979819246-1001\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache

Finally, if you had added the WAMP/apache2 directory to your Windows PATH that will also need to be deleted manually.