WAMP install help on Win11
All,
I have not used WAMP in over 25 years because my 20 servers are all Kubuntu Linux and use LAMP there, but we are having a power issue at the office where power was promised by the landlord, but not delivered, so we ran a temp connection, but that was removed as now having to pay for the installation.  Not the original agreement.
Anyway that leaves me with just the Win11 laptop.  Therefore needed to install WAMP as I develop in PHP.  Well downloaded the WAMP 64 .exe install file and ran it as admin.  It did not install correctly. WAMP screen would come up in Firefox, but PHPmyAdmin did not, so tried 3 more times.  All failed!  Even did a separate download and install of PHPmyAdmin which never worked.
So today I am trying again,  Watched the video at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJKL-0guwa0
Now he shows that you get a screen asking for upgrades to several MS C libraries, which never appeared in any of my previous install attempts, so erased the old .exe file in the “Downloads” dir, and downloaded a new vesion.    Ran that new version in Admin again and it failed, so thought and therefore performed a purge on WAMP.  Now when I attempt an install whether the install dir is “c:\wamp” or “d:\wamp” I always gets an error saying that is an incorrect directory so it cannot install.  I’m guessing it did not purge the registry keys, which is why the errors, but not sure.
I will appreciate all help here and procedures to effect the full purge, so I can proceed with the new install.
Cheers!
TBNK

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629706/cant-completely-remove-uninstall-wamp64-files might help with uninstall

Did you try XAMPP instead? Tends to be quite reliable, purely in my personal experience.

Do you still have c:\wamp or d:\wamp? If so, delete the directories, reboot and try to install again. Did you try to reboot anyways?

Sorry will never use XAMPP as it has more than 100 times more issue than WAMP or LAMP, but thanks for the thought.

I guess some do not understand the term "PURGE" which means every single thing found concerning WAMP is gone even the 3 directories it was in. Im' not very good at it, but guess it is back to regedit to run a search on WMP there, as it seems to be the source of this error!
Cheers!
TBNK
